# Add Orderable Model to custom settings in Wagtail CMS

Tags: django, wagtail

I'd like to organize common site elements in an appropriate place. For example, site footer elements. As far as I know Site settings is a good approach. Everything was going OK until I decided to add Orderable model there to be able to build kind of iterable list with some items contain attributes "text", "URL link". I encountered a trouble, usual way I used to apply in page models didn't help me. Here is the code:

```
@register_setting
class SiteFooterSettings(BaseSetting):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Footer Settings')

    blog_title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    blog_article_button_text = models.CharField(_('Article Button Text'), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            heading=_('Our Blog'),
            children=[
                FieldPanel('blog_title'),
                FieldPanel('blog_article_button_text'),
            ],
            classname='collapsible'
        ),

        MultiFieldPanel(
            heading=_('Blog Menu Items'),
            children=[
                InlinePanel('blog_menu_items', label=_('Blog Menu Item')),
            ],
            classname='collapsible'
        ),
    ]


class SettingsBlogMenu(Orderable):
    page = ForeignKey('ds.SiteFooterSettings', related_name='blog_menu_items')
    blog_menu_item = models.CharField(_('Item'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    blog_menu_item_url = models.CharField(_('URL'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('blog_menu_item'),
        FieldPanel('blog_menu_item_url')
    ]
```

Usually I use ParentalKey to bind such kind of list to a page. Though during migration Django throw an error and advises to change it to Foreign key. Finally I get
    "KeyError at /admin/settings/ds/sitefootersettings/2/
    'blog_menu_items'

What's wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE. Recently I found this thread.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3435

First post includes very clear code example how to deal with. It worked for me.